# how to restrict null session

Tags: windows, security

I've changed the following things in regedit and restarted PC to restrict null session:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA
Value Name: RestrictAnonymous
Data Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 1

Value Name: RestrictAnonymousSam
Data Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 1

Value Name: EveryoneIncludesAnonymous
Data Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 0
```

However,  I can still run and get null session.
net use //IP /u:"" ""
command completed successfully

I've also done "Disable NetBios over TCP/IP" but it didn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Null sessions are tricky to disable. Although a bit old, you should read [this presentation](http://www.hsc.fr/ressources/presentations/null_sessions/msrpc_null_sessions.pdf) about exploiting and protecting from null sessions to understand how they work and what options there are to restrict them (depending on your operating system).

"Disable NetBios over TCP/IP" didn't work because **null sessions** are unauthenticated SMB sessions, unrelated to NetBios.

Answer (score -1):

Firewall Configuration:
Ensure that your firewall settings are configured properly to block unauthorized access to SMB (Server Message Block) ports, such as TCP port 445.

Network Share Permissions:
Review the permissions set on your network shares to ensure that they are configured correctly and do not allow anonymous access.